# Gitlab-ci: how to run python script with cl arguments

Tags: python, bash, yaml, command-line-arguments, gitlab-ci

I want to run a python script, which expects cl arguments, before the actual build, so I added the following piece in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
.deploy_template: &template_name
  variables:
  - arg1: "https://some/url/"
  - arg2: "https://another/url/"
  - arg3: "https://one/more/url/"
  script:
  - python3 some/script/file.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
usage: file.py [-h] arg1 arg2 arg3

file.py: error: the following arguments are required: arg1 arg2 arg3
```

If the arguments are just strings (i.e. not variables), then it works fine, but it does not read the variables `$arg1` etc.

In the gitlab docs it is mentioned, that I can use the bash syntax to supply variables, so `$arg1` must the correct reference.

I use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in the script to get the cl arguments.

What is the correct way to call the variables in gitlab-ci.yml as the python script arguments?

Answer (score 6):

Your *variables* is a list, but it requires a dictionary. Just remove the `-` from it.

```
.deploy_template: &template_name
  variables:
    arg1: "https://some/url/"
    arg2: "https://another/url/"
    arg3: "https://one/more/url/"
  script:
  - python3 some/script/file.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

[More about yaml syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html)